# How to change passed-in modifier before using it?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm trying to add some conditional logic to the modifier parameter in my custom composable before using it. How can this be done? For example

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(index: Int, myModifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    if (index == 0) {
        myModifier.background(Color.Red)
    } else {
        myModifier.background(Color.Blue)
    }

    Column(modifier = myModifier) { 
        ...
    }
```

Compose simply ignores changes made to `myModifier`

For now, I'm creating a new variable of type Modifier and using that instead, but I'm wondering if there is a better way using the original passed-in modifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. `Modifier` has an infix function `.then()` that concatenates Modifiers. So in my example, the right way to do this would be:

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(index: Int, myModifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    val backgroundMod = if (index == 0) {
        Modifier.background(Color.Red)
    } else {
        Modifier.background(Color.Blue)
    }

    Column(modifier = myModifier.then(backgroundMod)) { 
        ...
    }
```

This will keep the passed-in modifier and concatenate the background color Modifier to it.

Answer (score 1):

Its not being ignored, but it won't work by simply calling

```
myModifier.background( <color> )
```

because you aren't setting it to the same `Modifier` instance or **any** `Modifier` instance that your `Column` will use.

You cannot do this and it won't compile

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(index: Int, myModifier : Modifier = Modifier) {

    myModifier = if (index == 0) {
        Modifier.background(Color.Red)
    } else {
        Modifier.background(Color.Blue)
    }

    Column(modifier = myModifier) { ... }
}
```

because the `Modifier` parameter (**myModifier**) is implicitly `val` and its `final`, so you'll see a compile error

> Val cannot be reassigned

However you can do something like this,

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(index: Int) {

    val myModifier = if (index == 0) {
        Modifier.background(Color.Red)
    } else {
        Modifier.background(Color.Blue)
    }

    Column(modifier = myModifier) { ... }
}
```

or something like this,

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(
    index : Int,
    myModifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Column(
        modifier = myModifier
            .background(
                if (index == 0) Color.Red else Color.Blue
            )
    ) { ... }
}
```

or when passing it to the `MyComposable`. I'm assuming that `index` is just used for a conditional background color though so I removed it as a parameter below

```
    // ... Somewhere in your composable outside ...

    val index = 5        
 
    MyComposable(
        // removed index arg
        myModifier = Modifier
            .background(
                if (index == 0) Color.Red else Color.Blue
            )    
    )
}


...
...
...


@Composable
fun MyComposable(
    // removed index param
    myModifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Column(modifier = myModifier)
    ) { ... }
}
```

I personally prefer the third approach, where `Modifier` properties of a root/parent composable are controlled outside,  in your case the `Column`(root/parent) background of your `MyComposable` contents.

Comment: Thanks! I agree the 3rd approach is best. However it won't work in my case. Setting the background color was just a simple example but in my actual use case there are many things I need to change based on the index, and I would rather hide that all in the custom composable instead of having calling composables deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

> Compose simply ignores changes made to myModifier

It doesn't ignore but when you chain Modifiers you create new instance of Modifier if any part of it has changed.

And Modifiers also get recomposed when the variable they read changes, in your instance when `Modifier.background()` changes there is a new Modifier created using part of the Modifier that doesn't change, in the example below size and the new Modifier for background.

You need to assign this new Modifier to your Composables

[image]

```
@Composable
private fun ModifierRecompositionSample() {
    var counter by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    Column {

        val myModifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()

        Text(text = "MyModifier: $myModifier", modifier = myModifier)


        val newModifier = if (counter == 0) {
            myModifier.background(Color.Red)
        } else {
            myModifier.background(Color.Blue)
        }

        Text(text = "MyModifier: $myModifier", modifier = myModifier)
        Text(
            color = Color.White,
            text = "newModifier: ${newModifier.hashCode()}, newModifier: $newModifier",
            modifier = newModifier
        )

        Button(onClick = { counter++ }) {
            Text("Counter: $counter")
        }
    }
}
```

You can check out this question if you with to investigate composition phases and Modifier recomposition

[How I can display data for specific item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74166690/how-i-can-display-data-for-specific-item)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example! I did not know that a new Modifier is created every time it changes. I thought it would be the same object in memory, but I guess not